# query regarding mocking singleton in swift ,ios using xctest?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

this is not a question regarding that should we use singleton or not. but rather mocking singleton related.
this is just a sample example, as i was reading about mocking singleton is tough. so i thought let me give a try.
i am able to mock it but not sure is this a correct approach ?

```
protocol APIManagerProtocol {
    static var sharedManager: APIManagerProtocol {get set}
    func doThis()

}

class APIManager: APIManagerProtocol {
    static var sharedManager: APIManagerProtocol = APIManager()
    private init() {
    }

    func doThis() {

    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var apiManager: APIManagerProtocol?
    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }
    convenience init(_ apimanager: APIManagerProtocol){
        self.init()
        apiManager = apimanager
    }

    func DoSomeRandomStuff(){
        apiManager?.doThis()
    }
}

import Foundation
@testable import SingleTonUnitTesting

class MockAPIManager: APIManagerProtocol {
    static var sharedManager: APIManagerProtocol = MockAPIManager()

    var isdoThisCalled = false

    func doThis(){
        isdoThisCalled = true
    }
    private init(){

    }
}

class ViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    var sut: ViewController?
    var mockAPIManager: MockAPIManager?

    override func setUp() {
        mockAPIManager = MockAPIManager.sharedManager as? MockAPIManager
        sut = ViewController(mockAPIManager!)
    }


    func test_viewController_doSomeRandomStuffs(){
        sut?.DoSomeRandomStuff()
        XCTAssertTrue(mockAPIManager!.isdoThisCalled)
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        sut = nil
        mockAPIManager = nil
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is right: Avoid repeated references to the singleton directly throughout the code, but rather inject object that conforms to the protocol.

What’s not quite right is that you are testing something internal to the `MockAPIManager` class. The mock is only there to serve a broader goal, namely to test your business logic (without external dependencies). So, ideally, you should be testing something that is exposed by `APIManagerProtocol` (or some logical result of that).

So, let’s make this concrete: For example, let’s assume your API had some method to retrieve the age of a user from a web service:

```
public protocol APIManagerProtocol {
    func fetchAge(for userid: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Int, Error>) -> Void)
}
```

(Note, by the way, that the `static` singleton method doesn’t belong in the protocol. It’s an implementation detail of the API manager, not part of the protocol. No controllers that get a manager injected will ever need to call `shared`/`sharedManager` themselves.)

And lets assume that your view controller (or perhaps better, its view model/presenter) had a method to retrieve the age and create an appropriate message to be shown in the UI:

```
func buildAgeMessage(for userid: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    apiManager?.fetchAge(for: userid) { result in
        switch result {
        case .failure:
            completion("Error retrieving age.")

        case .success(let age):
            completion("The user is \(age) years old.")
        }
    }
}
```

The API manager mock would then implement the method:

```
class MockAPIManager: APIManagerProtocol {
    func fetchAge(for userid: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Int, Error>) -> Void) {
        switch userid {
        case "123":
            completion(.success(42))

        default:
            completion(.failure(APIManagerError.notFound))
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could test the logic of building this string to be shown in your UI, using the mocked API rather than the actual network service:

```
class ViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {
    var viewController: ViewController?

    override func setUp() {
        viewController = ViewController(MockAPIManager())
    }

    func testSuccessfulAgeMessage() {
        let e = expectation(description: "testSuccessfulAgeMessage")
        viewController?.buildAgeMessage(for: "123") { string in
            XCTAssertEqual(string, "The user is 42 years old.")
            e.fulfill()
        }
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 1)
    }

    func testFailureAgeMessage() {
        let e = expectation(description: "testFailureAgeMessage")
        viewController?.buildAgeMessage(for: "xyz") { string in
            XCTAssertEqual(string, "Error retrieving age.")
            e.fulfill()
        }
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 1)
    }
}
```

---

> i was reading about mocking singleton is tough

The notion is that if you have these `APIManager.shared` references sprinkled throughout your code, it’s harder to swap them out with the mock object. Injecting solves this problem.

Then, again, if you’ve now injected this `APIManager` instance everywhere to facilitate mocking and have eliminate all of these `shared` references, it begs the question that you wanted to avoid, namely why use a singleton anymore?